# How to mount the CD-ROM on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, data-cd

How to mount the CD-ROM on Solaris 10 without knowing the CD-ROM device name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do want to mount a CD read-only with:

```
mount -F hsfs -o ro /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

I have never used any solaris machines with multiple CDs myself, but I assume you can use `/dev/sr1` etc. for the other drives.

Comment: This is easier than providing the specific CD-ROM device name.

Comment: Except for it doesn't work if you do a minimal Solaris 9 install.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the CD-ROM device name using the `iostat` command.

   ```
   # iostat -En
   c0d0             Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Model: VBOX HARDDISK   Revision:  Serial No: VB8abc1378-4a46 Size: 17.18GB <17179803648 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 0
   c1t0d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VBOX     Product: CD-ROM           Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 2.25GB <2254110720 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 8 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   ```

   The CD-ROM device name is `c1t0d0`.
2. Mount the CD-ROM

   ```
   # mount -r -F hsfs /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0 /cdrom
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the cdrom is not automatically mounted then you don't have the volfs service up

```
svcs -a|grep volfs
online         Jun_05   svc:/system/filesystem/volfs:default
```

Doing

```
svcadm enable volfs
```

Will renable the daemon and mount automatically the cdroms under /cdrom/cdrom# where # will be a number.

Otherwise you can do as Adam Siemion mentioned in is answer, use iostat and then mount the cd manually.